# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items.map is not a function using react

Tags: reactjs, promise, typeerror

get the following error when trying to output my list
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items.map is not a function

trying to output my json list using map but seems to fail, i know that this.state.data contains myjson as im able to console.log it. cant see why I GET THIS ERROR. below using react calling json using external file know it might eb basic problem cant seem to get it work

```
  JSON CODE

{
"vehicles": [
    {
        "id": "x",
        "modelYear": "98",
        "url": "/api/vehicle/tt",
        "media": [
            {
                "name": "vehicle",
                "url": "/images/1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "z",
        "modelYear": "99",
        "url": "/api/vehicle/ff",
        "media": [
            {
                "name": "vehicle",
                "url": "/images/2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },

 ]
}

export const getData = (data) => {

return fetch('http://localhost:9968/api/vehicle')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) => {
return response.json()
})

  import { getData } from '../api';

  export default
  class VehicleList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data : null
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await getData();
    this.setState({data: response})
    }

render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        let items = this.state.data


        return  (
            <div>
            {items.map(item => <h4>{item.id}</h4>)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
```

}

Comment: Whenever you get an error like this, always debug your code and set a breakpoint  where you're getting the error and look at what the variable holds. In this case, inspecting `items` would show that it's an object with a single "vehicles" property. Alternately, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 2))` to log the shape of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JSON you shared it's nested under `vehicles`. Have you tried:

```
{items.vehicles.map(item => <h4>{item.id}</h4>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data belongs to an object, inside a key called `vehicles`. Looks like you'll need:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        let items = this.state.data.vehicles


        return  (
            <div>
            {items.map(item => <h4>{item.id}</h4>)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
```